# <option selected = "selected"> issues in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I'm having issues with setting a default value in a dropdown menu in IE9. It seems to work on other browsers. All my searches yielded people trying to use JQuery to set that attribute. But I'm not using JQuery at all. Here's a sample:

```
<select id="selectType" name="selectType">
<option label="1" selected="selected">1</option>
<option label="2">2</option>
<option label="3">3</option>
</select>
```

I forgot to add that the problem is that it's displaying a blank field as the default instead of "1".

Comment: It should work fine. Are you sure you aren't just hitting F5 / clicking refresh and having the browser give you current form values instead of default values?

Comment: This is not a duplicate as suggested (there is no JavaScript involved in the question). Instead, it appears to be non-reproduceable and caused by something not disclosed in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work just fine, although personally I would take into account that `selected` is a boolean attribute and therefore its presence is all that is required:

```
<option label="1" selected>1</option>
```

That being said, I'm not sure `label` is a valid attribute there. I'm fairly sure they're inteded for `<optgroup>` tags. Try removing that attribute.

Comment: All right. That's strange, but maybe that's just what happens with UI elements like that.

Comment: Spoke too soon. I was viewing the wrong page.

Comment: AAH! Yes, that's happened to me in the past!

Comment: Forgot to add, making it just <option selected> without the "selected" value worked on IE9. Thanks.

Comment: @ModoModo, then the problem was something very different from the question, since `selected="selected"` works just fine on IE.

Comment: Jukka, what could it have been ?