# Select option not dynamically set on IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have looked at all the answers related to this, but still cannot figure out. Please help.
I have a jquery code as below :

```
$('#DDPrimaryServiceLine').find('option:contains("' + rowData['Primary_Service_Line'] + '")').attr("selected", true);
```

`rowData` is generated from ajax through DB call. Also originally the select is empty ,it is getting dynamically populated at run time. By Default it has null as selected.

On running, the drop down displays default selected null in `IE9`, though it works perfectly well in Google Chrome.

Please suggest. (I tried writing

```
$("#DDPrimaryServiceLine option:selected").removeAttr('selected');
```

too in my code. But doesn't work )

Comment: You should be setting the `val()` of the `select` and not selecting the `option`. Also use `prop()` and not `attr()` to change properties like `selected`.

Comment: Wow ! I was trying with val too like $('#DDPrimaryServiceLine').find("option[value='" + rowData['Primary_Service_Line'] + "']").attr("selected", true); but it wasnt working. Changing attr() to prop() works sexy :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment as answer:

You should be setting the `val()` of the `select` and not selecting the `option`, however if you want to change the selected property of an `option`, use `prop()` and not `attr()`. This sets the correct internal values (and triggers selection changes) and does not just change the display attributes.

e.g.

```
$('#DDPrimaryServiceLine').find('option:contains("' + rowData['Primary_Service_Line'] + '")').prop("selected", true);
```

`prop` has the added advantage that the values returned are not just strings and it will correctly return `true` and `false` *boolean* values if the attribute is "true" or "false".

Answer (score 0):

Does the solution here help [Best way to unselect a <select> in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857781/best-way-to-unselect-a-select-in-jquery?lq=1)

using .prop("selected", false) instead of .removeAttr() ?

Comment: Sorry my question was of setting a value nor removing it.

Comment: The last part of your question says "Please suggest. (I tried writing

$("#DDPrimaryServiceLine option:selected").removeAttr('selected');
too in my code. But doesn't work )"

Comment: Yes because at some sites they mentioned remove the previous selected values before setting the one. So that was what I had tried.

Answer (score 0):

I need to see also your html code to see where the error can be. Check this link:
[ie9 select default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212174/option-selected-selected-issues-in-ie9)

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: if I could make comments to others,
I don't have enough reputation yet ;)